# React native Plaid Link OAuth iOS - after completing oauth authentication in external browser, redirects to app but not starts from where its left off

Tags: react-native, oauth, plaid

I've integrated plaid using react-native-plaid-link-sdk in my react-native ios project. For OAuth flow, as mentioned in the document, I've added the redirect uri for OAuth flow. It works fine, where I was successfully able to redirect and connect the User's bank account in the external browser. Once done, it redirects back to the application. But in the app it is not resumed from where it left off from the plaid view, instead the app restarts where the HANDOFF event in plaid is not invoked. So I'm unable to update the selected accounts and other details to the server.

I've followed the OAuth requirements given here https://github.com/plaid/react-native-plaid-link-sdk#oauth-requirements

react-native version is 0.68.0
plaid sdk version is 7.4.0

Please clarify if any other additional implementations should be done to handle OAuth flow in react native ios. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

First, make sure the appdelegate is correctly set up, if relevant to your application, as described in https://plaid.com/docs/link/oauth/#react-native-on-ios:

"The `PlaidLink` component handles Universal Links by default. For integrations that use `PlaidLink.openLink`, Universal Links will not be handled by default. The `useDeepLinkRedirector` hook must be invoked by the component that calls `PlaidLink.openLink`."

Second, upgrade to the latest version of the React Native SDK, which has improved handling of OAuth redirects.

If neither of these suggestions works, please go ahead and submit a ticket to Plaid Support.

(Credit for this answer goes to Nathan from Plaid Developer Support, I am just passing along his troubleshooting suggestions!)